# real device connecting Automation Script is not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, server, appium

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\DaniThomas\PycharmProjects\python_selenium_automation\MobileUI.py", line 14, in <module>
    webdriver=webdriver.Remote('127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',desired_cap)
  File "C:\Users\DaniThomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 230, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\DaniThomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\DaniThomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 320, in start_session    
    response = self.execute(RemoteCommand.NEW_SESSION, w3c_caps)
  File "C:\Users\DaniThomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute    
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\DaniThomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Device 721ac4c6 was not in the list of connected devices
Stacktrace:
UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Device 721ac4c6 was not in the list of connected devices
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)
```

Need solution to this below mentioned problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]

Comment: Before running the test, make sure to run, `adb devices` and if the device serial number is shown, then, ideally this issue shouldn't be happening.

Comment: the device serial number is showing but it is throwing this same error